# How to eliminate brain fog quickly?

Tags: brain, fatigue, brain-fog, mental-exhaustion

After 6 hours on a computer, I feel mentally exhausted. What can one do to re-energize the brain? Besides sleeping to speed up recovery, how could one eliminate brain fog quickly? I eat healthful foods and exercise. I also don't drink, smoke, or do drugs. Furthermore, I'm not depressed or down emotionally in any way.

Comment: Get up and get moving. Exercise.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to feel exhausted after 6 hours straight on a computer.
Stop taking fluoride and hallogens in water, that will help any latent/semi permanent brain fog, also take breaks, every hours, of 10-25 minutes.

Other poisonous substances can cause "brain fog".

Also look for Iodine food source to detoxify fluoride and hallogens (raw cranberry smoothie is good source,think it's 2 onzes for 100%, potatoes are good too, beans also) . Theres also Choline for cognitive functions, and alot of other minerals act on that aswell. 
"
Look for fluoride and sodium laureth sulfate free toothpaste, or make your own, it seems sesame oil kills bacteria responsible for decay,although I have not seen enough proof of it.

I recommend eating sunflower seed(3/4 or 1 cup) or pumpkin seeds , or peanuts http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3076/2 , to get most of the nutrients everyone need, it helps the mental functions.  (Source USDA)

Get F.Lux(reduces blue light) and reduce kelvins to 3500 you can also get Pangobright for even lower light,although in advanced setting F.Lux lets you do it also. If you don't want you can always wear glare+blue light reducing glasses.

Use zoom to read on computer press Ctrl and scroll up with the mouse wheel (or install an app that does it manually).

Comment: You make some remarkable claims here and there's not a single reference to support any of them.